# Synology Hybrid RAID 2x2TB and 2x4TB combinations

Tags: raid, nas, synology

I currently have 2 x 2TB HDD in my 4 bay Synology NAS (Synology DS916+ running DSM 6.0.2) in SHR mirroring. Since I am running out of space I was thinking of buying two 4TB HDDs to supplement the existing.

Can I create one volume with 2x2 and 2x4 in some redundant setup? I would like to have (2x2) + 4 + 4 in a SHR RAID-5 setup. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I bought 2x 4TB disks and placed them in the two empty slots and hoped for the best. ... And to answer the question: **Yes, you can.**

1. Insert new drives into the empty bays
2. Open up "Storage Manager" > Volumnes
3. Extend the volume to include the extra disks
4. Wait three days for it to extend. The extra space will not be available until after this time.

Notes:

- The end result is a "RAID-5" array with 7TiB of usable space.
- If I had the space I'd would've moved the existing data onto a temporary hard drive and then recreated SHR volume to save time.
- The volume was formatted to BTRFS using SHR(2?).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would probably have to expand the SHR volume. So you would have to plug in the 2 x 4 TB drives then expand the current SHR into those drives.

**Add a Hard Drive to Expand Storage Capacity**

If there are empty hard drive slots on your Synology NAS, you can install additional hard drives and add them to an existing volume or disk group.

**Before You Start**

Before starting, make sure the hard drives that you want to add meet the following size requirements:
For SHR: The capacity of the hard drive you wish to add must be equal to or larger than the largest hard drive in the volume or disk group, or be equal to any of the hard drives in the volume or disk group. For example, if your SHR volume is composed of three hard drives – 2 TB, 1.5 TB, and 1 TB respectively – then the capacity of the new hard drive must be at least 2 TB or equal to 1.5 TB or 1 TB.

Have a look at the synology guide:
https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/volume_diskgroup_expand_add_disk